# Seperate initials in freemarker

Tags: freemarker

Is it possible to set points in initials? 
For example to change MAW into M.A.W.

I tried keep_before, but it doesn't work. 
?keep_before(" ")+". "}
Result: MAW.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like:

```
${'MAW'?replace('','.')[1..]}
```

`'MAW'?replace('','.')` will result in `.M.A.W.`, which you can "substring" by using the range `[1..]`.

See

- https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_string.html#ref_builtin_replace
- https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/dgui_template_exp.html#dgui_template_exp_stringop_slice

Answer (score 0):

It's easiest to do with regular expressions: `${initials?replace('.', '$0.', 'r')}`. It's maybe nicer if you wrap this into a `#function` though (`<#function dotify(s)><#return s?replace('.', '$0.', 'r')></#function>`, and then `${dotify(initals)}`), especially if you need to do this on multiple places.

Answer (score 0):

If your letters are in `name` try:

```
<#list 0..(name?length-1) as idx>${name[idx]}.</#list>
```